# iOS storyboard Facebook login tutorial failing at connect the delegate outlet to the files owner

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I did my best to find relevant entries to this question but with no luck. I am following the Facebook Login tutorial for iOS (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial) and hit a frustrating snag. The instructions are to "In the Connections inspector, connect the delegate outlet to the File's Owner.".

I am using storyboard to build my app and the selected view in this screenshot has the FBLoginView class as instructed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/clTJJ.jpg

I believe I have connected the Login View correctly, however, when I go to implement the callbacks suggested in the tutorial:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
    self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}
```

I get the error: "Property 'profilePictureView' not found on object of type 'EPI_HYS_AccountPage *'"with EPI_HYS_AccountPage being the class behind 'Account Page'.

I have followed the instructions to the letter as far as I know but am willing to double check anything you think may be relevant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://m-farhan.com/2014/03/ios-facebook-sdk-tutorial/

try this this is detailed tutorial how ever approach you are using. I don't have much knowledge. Sorry if this is not right answer

Comment: Great find mate, I appreciate it.